# Store Jquery Draggable Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

How can I get the X,Y co-ords of a JQueryUI draggable object, when it is dropped, and POST them to something (a java servlet) using AJAX?

Im trying to store the location of it in a database, ive got the handler to do that done, Im an okay backend guy, but I suck with JavaScript!

Comment: When you drag an element, its left and top positions are updated. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just includes that AJAX call you might be able to use.

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var x = ui.position.left;
        var y = ui.position.top;

        $.post("servlet", {
            x: x,
            y: y
        }.success(function() {
            console.log(event+" "+ui+" "+ui.position);
        }.error(function() {
            console.log("FAILED: "+event+" "+ui+" "+ui.position);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help. You can get the required data from the callback function arguments

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#drag_area" ).draggable({
    stop: function(event, ui){
        console.log(event);
        console.log(ui);
        console.log(ui.position);   
        var left = ui.position.left;
        var top = ui.position.top;  
    }
});
});
```

From ui.position you can get top and left position of the object after the dragging has stopped

Answer (score 0):

if you look in the jQuery ui [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) method documentation under events, you'll see the stop method. In this method you can look at the draggable elements axis option and then do your ajax call to update the database.

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
   stop: function(event, ui) {
      //edit for my mistake
       //var axis = $( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "axis" );
       var axis = ui.position;
   }
});
```

Comment: axis option if set to true, constrains the drag either to x or y axis. The above code returns false.

Comment: Ya that's my stupidity. it's ui.position to get the current positions.